# implementation with different signature java

Tags: java, generics

While I was developing an architecture of classes to meet my need, I have confronted this case. I have an abstract class that has some methods inside it that must be implemented by subclass, but in the subclass I discovered that I needed to implement with signature that  inherits from the first on.

To show you what I mean:

```
// person class
public abstract class Person
{ 
  protected void abstract workWith(Object o) throws Exception;
}

//developer class
public class Developer extends Person
{// i want to implement this method with Computer parametre instead of Object and throws `//DeveloperException instead of Exception`
 protected void workWith(Computer o) throws DeveloperException
 {
  //some code here lol install linux ide server and stuff 
 }
}

// exception class 
public class DeveloperException extends Exception
{

}
```

Is there any way to do it? I do not know if it is possible with generic. Thank you so much.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you in control of the `Person` class? (And use the Java naming conventions: `Developer`, not `developer`.)

Comment: sorry it was just a mistake 
  i thought that the code explains every thing 
i want to implement the abstract method that we find in Person in Developer with signature that inherits from that we find in parent class

Comment: Since it's permissible to use a subclass (`Developer`) anywhere you could use the superclass (`Person`), the subclass has to be able to accept any input that the superclass could, so the subclass method can be more liberal in what it accepts, but not more restrictive. Similarly, the subclass can be more specific about what it will return, but not more liberal. Generics can make this work, as @dbyme describes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can definitely use generics for this:

```
public abstract class Person<T, U extends Exception> { 
  protected abstract void workWith(T t) throws U;
}

class Developer extends Person<Computer, DeveloperException> {
  protected void workWith(Computer c) throws DeveloperException {
    //implementation code
  }
}
```

This accomplishes what you want, but we would need a lot more details regarding your use case to determine whether this is the right design to use.

Comment: oh that is great  i was sure that it was the only issue  thank you @dbyme

Comment: +1 for generic exceptions, which seem to be rarely discussed.